# I need the ID that's held inside of the URL to update a table in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a slideshow on a webpage, the user clicks through to next one. When the user clicks through, the ID changes inside of the URL address. I need a way of updating a table each time the user changes onto the next slide. I want to save where the user is, to then reload their progress at a later date. The slideshow code is all in one html page. Snippet of 2 sections (slides) below:

```
<section class="aligncenter">
    <span class="background light" style="background-image: url('istudy_slides_images/abstract2.jpg')"/></span>
        <div class="wrap" id="slide=6">
        <div class="wrap">
             <h1>Stress is often defined as when an individual perceives the demands upon them to exceed there perceived ability to cope</h1>
        </div>
</section>

<!-- SLIDE 6 -->
<section>
    <span class="background" style="background-image:url('istudy_slides_images/balance.jpg')"></span>
          <div class="wrap" id="slide=7">
          <div class="alignright size-50 bg-trans-dark">
             <p class="text-subtitle text-serif">"In the end, it's all a question of balance" - Rohinton Mistry</p><br>
             <h3><strong>Balance</strong></h3>
             <p>A common source of stress and anxiety is when we lack balance within our lives.</p>
             <p><strong>Task Two:</strong> Consider whether you have the correct balance in you're life.<br>Are there any improvements you can make to your life work balance to improve your wellbeing?</p>
           </div>
           </div>
</section>
```

Screenshot of the URL which shows the id (can I use this to update the table in my database `checkPointMod` each time the id changes? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated I've been stuck on this one for a while. If the best way to do this is with cookies/sessions please could someone give me some guidance?

[image: URL Screenshot showing the ID]

Using: Webslides.tv for the slides https://webslides.tv/#slide=2

Comment: You can pass that id as query string.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with an entry in the database? Just use local storage or something else on client side

Comment: @kuh-chan I need it to update the table in my local server of where the user is, so it can save the progress of how far a user has got through the slideshow, then my next step is to somehow re-load where they picked off once logging back in :)

Comment: @T.C Are you using any plugins for slide show?

Comment: `$_GET['slide']` this's like the basics of PHP. and instead of saving this into the db, you can use sessions and cookies.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi Using https://webslides.tv/#slide=3  for the slideshow

Comment: @T.C I still don't see the problem. Your slideshow works via Javascript, not via PHP. So there is no need to store anything on the server. Did you write the slideshow yourself or did you use some library?

Comment: @julekgwa `$_GET` won't work as `slide` is no query parameter but the fragment identifier

Comment: please see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Thank you @julekgwa I'll check that out. This is stressing me out to the max (with being a beginner)

Comment: @T.C use local storage, there is no need to use the server for this. On the part where you initialize your slideshow you can check the local storage. If an entry is set, pass it to the slideshow: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage https://github.com/webslides/WebSlides/wiki/Core-API#goToSlide

Comment: Thanks @kuh-chan I'll check this out, its all very confusing nothing seems to be very straight forward but I'll check those links out :)

Comment: remember `localStorage` has no expiration date, the data will be available the next day, week, or year.

Comment: @julekgwa thank you, ah that's exactly what I need. I basically need the data constantly available no matter how long after the user logs in. I'll check local storage out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a general approach to rather than exact code. So what you can do, you can get that hash parameter in the URL using the JavaScript like this,

```
let slideID = window.location.hash
```

Then you can use local storage to store that id so that you can use that to navigate the the user to current slide like this,

```
localStorage.setItem('slideid', slideID);
```

Then on reload of page you can retriev that `slideID` like this

```
localStorage.getItem('slideid');
```

Comment: Thank you, can I just quickly ask, would this code  for local storage need to be separate from the html web slide code and just called in via `<script>` tag ?